# Entity Framework Core 2.0 many-to-many relationships same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using *Entity Framework Core 2.0* to map exist DB, the DB has two tabels: `Teams` and `SupportTeam`.

**Team Fields:** ID, Name

**TeamSupport**: TeamID (ForeignKey on Team  Table), SupportTeamID (ForeignKey on Team  Table)

I tried to map them as following:

```
 public class Team
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }

     public List<TeamSupport> SupportTeams { get; set; }

 }

 public class TeamSupport
 {
     public int TeamId { get; set; }
     public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

     public int SupportTeamId { get; set; } // In lack of better name.
     public virtual Team SupportTeam { get; set; }
 }
```

But I had the follwing error when i run "add-migration":

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'Team.SupportTeams' of type 'List'. Either
>   manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

Answer (score 2):

The `TeamSupport` entity has **two** *reference* navigation properties to `Team` (which define two many-to-one relationships between `TeamSupport` and `Team`), but the `Team` entity has only **one** *collection* navigation property, hence EF does not know how to map it (to `Team.Team` or `Team.SupportTeam`) and throws the exception in question.

In such scenarios you have to resolve the mapping explicitly. Usually it's enough to use `[InverseProperty]` data annotation, but multiple references to the same table always lead to *multiple cascade paths* problem, which requires turning the delete cascade off for one or more of the relationships. And the later can be done only with fluent configuration, so it's better to do the whole mapping with fluent configuration as well.

The minimal configuration needed by your model the way it is now is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TeamSupport>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Team)
    .WithMany(e => e.SupportTeams);

modelBuilder.Entity<TeamSupport>()
    .HasOne(e => e.SupportTeam)
    .WithMany()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Note that since there is no corresponding collection navigation property, the second relationships configuration uses the parameterless `WithMany` overload to indicate that. In case you decide to add such collection to the model

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<TeamSupport> SupportTeams { get; set; }
    public List<TeamSupport> SupportOfTeams { get; set; } // <--
}
```

don't forget to specify that in the corresponding mapping

```
.WithMany(e => e.SupportOfTeams)
```

otherwise EF will create a third relationship.

For more info, see [Relationhips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) section of the EF Core documentation.

Comment: in this case the SupportTeams type is List<TeamSupport>. how can I reaturn SupportTeams as List<Team>.

Comment: If you mean at model level, you can't currently as mentioned in the [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) subsection in the documentation link from the answer: *"Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table **are not yet supported**."* But you can always extract the `SupportTeam` property from `TeamSupport` list using LINQ `Select`.