# EF Core 5 many to many relationship to the same table?

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many

A product can have many other related products. The following creates the join table perfectly but when I add a product to another product's RelatedProducts I get the following error on save: 'The value of 'ProductAssociation.ProductID' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.'

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(x => x.RelatedProducts)
                .WithMany(r => r.RelatedProducts)
                .UsingEntity<ProductAssociation>(
                    x => x.HasOne(p => p.RelatedProduct).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.RelatedProductID),
                    x => x.HasOne(p => p.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
                    x => x.ToTable("ProductAssociations"));
```

Comment: Seems such a thing is not supported...I haven't found a single example that involves the same table

Comment: `RelatedProducts` can't be two sides of one association.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a similar answer
[Entity Framework Core 2.0 many-to-many relationships same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839390/entity-framework-core-2-0-many-to-many-relationships-same-table)

I also solved it with that provide link above like this in core 3+.

**Product** table

```
public class Product
{
    // Other properties members ....
    
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> ProductOf { get; set; }
}
```

**Product Association** table "ProductSet"

```
public class ProductSet
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SubProductId { get; set; }
}
```

**OnModelCreating()**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Products)
    .WithMany(e => e.ProductOf)
    .UsingEntity<ProductSet>(
        e => e.HasOne<Product>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId),
        e => e.HasOne<Product>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.SubProductId));
```

Comment: This works. The second collection was the key. The actual code that worked for me was this: 
`code` modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.RelatedProducts)
                    .WithMany(r => r.RelatedProductsOf)
                    .UsingEntity<ProductAssociation>(
                        x => x.HasOne(p => p.RelatedProduct).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.RelatedProductID),
                        x => x.HasOne(p => p.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                        );

Comment: I want to order in sub-products, so I added an ordering column to the ProductSet table, but I couldn't make an order in one way, can you help?

Comment: i added a new column as Ordering to ProductSet table. How can I sort using the ordering column in this table?